# Bounding box for 2 points in a plane

Tags: c, algorithm, math, geometry, bounding-box

I have 2 points A and B in a plane. What I need to find is the points w, x, y and z so that I can have a uniform bounding box.
The conditions are a line formed by wx and yz are parallel to AB.
Similarly wBz and xAy are parallel must be parallel.
Also note that angle zwx and wxy are right angles. Basically wxyz has to be a square.

```
          z
       /   /
     B      /
  /          /
w             /  
 /             y
  /          /
   /      A 
    /  /
     x
```

Basically finding w, x, y and z is easy if line AB is parallel to x-axis or if AB is parallel to y-axis. I'm having trouble determining the points w,x,y and z when line AB is in an angle with x-axis (slope of line AB could be positive or negative).

Any comments/suggestions is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are we assuming that B is the midpoint of wz or that the box can slide 'left and right' along the wx, xy lines?

Comment: Consider moving this to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Does wBz need to be perpendicular to zy; or could the resulting box be a diamond shape rather than a square? If a diamond is fine then a diamond where the distance between wx and zy is 0 may be fine too (e.g. a line segment where w = z = B, and x = y = A).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat A and B as vectors in your plane, (xa, ya) and (xb, yb). Take the vector difference, to generate a vector, C, that points from A to B.

```
C = A - B = (xa - xb, ya - yb) = (xc, yc)
```

Rotate this vector 90 degrees in each direction, and scale by a half, to get D = (xd, yd) and E = (xe, ye).

```
D = (-yc/2, +xc/2)
E = -D = (+yc/2, -xc/2)
```

Use vector arithmetic to get the four points of the square.

```
w = B + D
x = A + D
y = A + E
z = B + E
```

**EDIT**: Fat fingers.

**EDIT2**: Forgot the factor of a half.

**EDIT3**: Vector rotation reference, as requested.

To figure out the vector rotation, one can, in general, perform multiplication with a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). In this case, the sin and cos factors of +/- pi/2 end up being +/- 1.

If matrix multiplication isn't your thing, draw on paper (or just imagine) a sample vector in any quadrant. Now rotate the paper 90 deg in either direction and see how the x and y components get swapped around and negated.

Comment: Thanks for the details @neirbowj. Does this work for any line in any quadrant in an x-y plane (2-d) regardless of the slope of the line?

Comment: Ok, so looks like that works for all lines. Can anyone point to some documentation on vector rotation in "English"? The reversing of x and y in D and E delta is kind of over my head! :)

Answer (score 1):

neirbowjs answer translated to more optimized solution, if optimization floats your boat.

Vars you know `(Ax, Ay, Bx, By)`;

Vars you solve for `(Wx, Wy, Xx, Xy, Yx, Yy,Zx, Zy)`;

```
float dx = By - Ay / 2;
float dy = Bx - Ax / 2;

float Wx = Ax - dx; 
float Wy = Ay + dy; 
float Zx = Ax + dx; 
float Zy = Ay - dy; 
float Xx = Bx - dx; 
float Xy = By + dy; 
float Yx = Bx + dx; 
float Yy = By - dy;
```